# how to split a string by whitespaces in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I split this by whitespaces. (the first lines is its header)

[image]

I try this code but error "index out of range" at  cbay.ABS = columnsC[5] because the second line return only 4 instead of 6 elements like in 1st line. I want the 2nd line also return 6 elements.

```
using (StringReader strrdr = new StringReader(strData))
{
    string str;
    while ((str = strrdr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //  str = str.Trim();
        if ((Regex.IsMatch(str.Substring(0, 1), @"J")) || (Regex.IsMatch(str.Substring(0, 1), @"C")))
        {
            columnsC = Regex.Split(str, " +");
            cbay.AC = columnsC[1];
            cbay.AU = columnsC[2];
            cbay.SA = columnsC[3];
            cbay.ABS = columnsC[5];
            // cbay.ABS = str;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe everybody besides me understands the question, but I don't.

Comment: you can test String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cbay.AC) instead of cbay.AC == null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get only words without redundant witespaces you could pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as second argument for the `Split` method of the `string` and if will remove all redundant "whitespaces" since it will split on each whitespace. Instead of using Regex check this simple example:

```
string inputString = "Some string   with  words     separated with multiple    blanck   characters";
string[] words = inputString.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string resultString = String.Join(" ", words); //joins the words without multiple whitespaces, this is for test only.
```

**EDIT** In your particular case, if you use this string where parts are separated with multiple whitespaces (at least three) it will work. Check the example:

```
string inputString = "J   16   16   13   3   3";
string[] words = inputString.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**EDIT2**:This is the simplest and the dummiest solution to your problem but I think it will work:

```
if(str.Length>0 && ((str[0]=="J") || (str[0]=="C")))
{
   columnsC = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   if((str[0]=="J")
   {
            cbay.AC = columnsC[1];
            cbay.AU = columnsC[2];
            cbay.SA = columnsC[3];
            cbay.ABS = columnsC[5];
   }
   else
   {
            cbay.AU = columnsC[1];
            cbay.SA = columnsC[2];
   }
}
```

Comment: I know, but I want every line return 6 elements. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the code? It will return you six strings. Just use `columnsC = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` instead of your code.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, it return 6 elements, but all value = empty, it must be value: C,empty,8,8,0,empty in the second line

Comment: Using one char (space) as separator and as empty value in the same time is bad idea. You'll lost positions in any way with this approach. If it's possible use zero or -1 or something for empty positions.

Comment: Yes, I have read the question. And my suggestion was for op. I wrote it here as answer for his latest comment.

Comment: this is data format from an external system, I must to read it );

Comment: Sorry, I'm not, my quesion is on the "C" line, 1st & 2nd line is ok.

Comment: the first line is header, i must read from the 2nd line and assign its value to its header

Comment: but in some case, the C line have full 6 elements as J and vice versa (J lines has <6 elements).sorry  for my english

Answer (score 0):

You could first replace multiple spaces with zeros and after that split on the remaining single spaces;

```
        var test = "test 1 2    3";
        var items = test.Replace("  ", "0").Split(' ');
```

You might get some 00 positions if there are many spaces, but that will still work I guess